# Modify Alpha bib style

Tags: bibtex

I'm working with Latex for the first time, so I don't quite understand the syntax of the bibliography styels.

For my thesis I need the citation to be 4 letters of author name/names and 2 numbers for year. For one author Mustermann [Must14], two autors [MuAn14], 3 authors [MuAB14]

The closest style I found was alpha. But it only shows 3 letters. Is there a way to easily modify it?

Comment: If you really use `biblatex` that should be possible. There might be BibTeX styles that can do this as well. In order to help you, it would be really appreciated if you could post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what your bibliography set-up looks like now. You could also tell us if you would like to use `biblatex`, or if you are stuck to any particular package (`natbib` etc.).

Comment: I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: It turns out I'm using bibTex, not biblatex. Also I'm not required to use any particualr package. I was just using the one that was already provided in the template.

I downloaded many bibTex styles which I found and the closest thing I found to what i need was the alpha.bst The only problem with it is that it shows 3 letters instead of 4.

About the MWE, I'm not sure what to post, as I don't have a specific error. It just a styling issue.

Also thank you so much for your welcome. I'm happy to join Tex.Sx :)

Comment: Would you be interested in using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) *with* [Biber](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) (for more information please see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)). Or would you rather stick with BibTeX?

Comment: I am open to any suggestions that will make this work. So biblatex with Biber would be fine by me

Comment: Do you really want "UtRO" for three authors "Uthor, Riter and Ontributor"? What about four or more names?

Comment: Yes UtRO for three authors, 4 Authors would be 4 letters of last name like UROX, 5 or more would be URO+

Comment: That seems quite possible save for the handling of three authors, that's going to be very tricky. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Not a good solution but works for now. I was able to modify the style file to ignore author if a key is specified, to format the label for 2, 3 or more authors manually. And for a single author I modified it to display 4 letters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add some more details to the answer? It is very good that you modified the `.sty` file, but you have to explain what you did otherwise this question will not be of help for future visitors.

Comment: Please shed more lights on your solution. As of now, like groping in the dark.